# how to process multiple JSON documents

Tags: sql-server, json, parsing

Using SQL Server 2017 I figured out how to parse a single JSON file containing a single JSON document for storing in a table.

However, I need to be able to process a file containing many JSON documents.  Are there built-in functions to do this?  Or can anyone explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Repeating myself somewhat, but I think I have this figured out.

1. I created a single file of 500 indivdual JSON documents
2. I manually added the JSON-specific opening and closing bracket racket as the
   1st and last lines.
3. I used this syntax to query the file:

   `select SQ1.*
   from OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Projects\json_files\dev_AllJsonDownload.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as mytest
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
   WITH (...colA ...colB ...colC ...colN ) as SQ1`

This returned what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above script to load multipe json files which are in a folder.
It's not working as expected then i did some ground work on this and achived that task using dynamic sql.

Suppose you have 3 files in a folder and you want to load those json files into sql server follow this script. This works well.

DECLARE @i INT = 1
Declare @SQL Varchar(200)
DECLARE @file Varchar(100)

WHILE(@i < 4)
BEGIN
   SET @file = '''E:\DrugBank\json1' + cast(@i AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.json''';
     --Select @file
   SET @SQL= 'INSERT INTO json_table SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK '+@file+', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e'

```
   PRINT @SQL
   EXEC (@SQL)
   SET @i = @i + 1 ;
```

END